# Why does this sum converge to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, riemann-zeta

In Van der Poorten's "[A Proof that Euler Missed...](http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf)", which outlines Apéry's proof that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational, the following sum appears:
$$
S=\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k^3) \binom{N+k}{k} \binom {N}{k}}.
$$
Van der Poorten remarks further on that $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to\infty} S = 0$ without giving a proof. This does not seem immediately obvious to me, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every term is less than $1/N^2$, so the total is less than $1/N$